# Is it worth it to buy champions right now?

Tags: league-of-legends

The season is almost over and the new one brings the fusion of IP and blue essence (BE). All the IP we have will become BE and our BE will be multiplied up to the value of IP.

Is it worth it to buy champions right now or should we wait until after the fusion to buy them?

**Example**

I want to buy Nami, who costs 6300IP. She will cost 6300BE next season. But with the fusion IP-BE can I save some IP if I buy her now?

Comment: The relative gain rate for IP/BE is going to be more or less the same (or faster). So whether you buy her now or not doesn't really matter. Whether or not it's "worth it" is up to you.

Comment: I'll never understand why so many people on this stack exchange site use downvotes when a question premise is incorrect when a simple "they're not actually going to be different" answer would be actually useful.  Not to mention I wouldn't have learned about Champion Shard gambling without the answers this question brought forth.

Comment: @Lunin 1) Because it shows a lack of research effort. Riot themselves have explained how the conversion is going to work, and it's not hard to find the info being discussed in multiple places. 2) Whether it's "worth it" is entirely opinion based, making it a bad question to begin with.

Comment: @MageXy While the information is findable on the blog posts about the change, it's kinda deep in there IIRC.  Also there are situations like this where you really should buy before/after the change where these facts can be quite hidden for market reasons.  That puts it in the same category as a lot of questions on other SE sites where having the answer plain helps both the asker and others.  As for 2), I feel that whether it is worth it is fairly clearly whether buying now would waste money.  Thank you for explaining the reasoning though, I may not agree but I appreciate knowing why :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Everything in the store will cost the same as before](https://nexus.leagueoflegends.com/en-us/2017/09/upcoming-changes-to-leveling-ip-rewards/)

The changes can be seen as IP being renamed to BE, and current blue essence being merged into it at an increased rate [(x6.5)](https://www.riftherald.com/lol-guides/2017/9/20/16340466/influence-points-to-blue-essence-conversion-guide)

The overall IP price of champions will remain the same

> So, what about the blue essence currently in your inventory? When preseason hits, we’ll scale it up proportionally (multiplying it by about 6.5 times) when calculating your new BE account balance. So if you already have 975 BE in loot, we’ll convert it into 6300 BE when preseason hits.
>   ([source](https://nexus.leagueoflegends.com/en-us/2017/09/upcoming-changes-to-leveling-ip-rewards/))

---

Do note that you may be able to gamble your IP to try to get more BE after the merge, by [buying champion shards](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/6xi6nt/how_to_get_84_more_blue_essence_preseason/)

Answer (score 3):

IP will simply be renamed to Blue Essence. All costs remain the same. All IP/BE items will be bought using BE.

The only difference is that your current Blue Essence will receive a small multiplication at the End of the Season (x6.5). This is also why it's currently worth buying Champion Shards, disenchanting and turning them into Blue Essence, which wields an ~8% net profit

On a purely economic standpoint, it's not worth buying Champions, it's better to invest all of your IP on Champion Shards, thus allowing yourself for an 8% increase to your IP (which will be called Blue Essence in Season 8)

Comment: Do you have any sources/evidence to back up your claims?

Comment: Regarding your last point: The 8% figure is NOT guaranteed. It is the *average* amount you could gain based on the number of expensive vs cheap champion shards currently available. It's quite possible that you lose IP as well. Your risk goes significantly higher the less champ shards you can afford.

Comment: Yes, that's true, hence the `~` =)